# Determine the least positive integer $n$ for which the cyclic group $(\Bbb Z_{60},+\pmod{60})$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

> Determine the least positive integer $n$ for which the cyclic group $(\Bbb Z_{60},+\pmod{60})$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

I have absolutely no idea how to even start this problem. I looked at Cayley's theorem and I think the answer is $S_{60}$ because each element must be mapped to another one. The other possibility is a permutation group of $S_5$ of order $60$ but that doesn't make sense because not every element would be mapped to a unique element in the permutation set.

Please help

Comment: What is the order of $(1\;2\;3)(4\;5\;6\;7)(8\;9\;10\;11\;12)\in S_{12}$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You need a symmetric group with an element of order $60$. Think about how to calculate the order of a permutation when you write it as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: I see, but doesn't every element of Z60 need to be mapped to an element of the group it is isomorphic to? If there are only 12 elements in S12 then how can each element of Z60 be mapped to one?

Comment: The number of elements in $S_n$ is $n!$ for all $n$, @SammyDavis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The orders of $(1,2,3), (4, 5,6,7), (8,9,10,11,12)$ are $3$, $4$, and $5$, respectively. They are disjoint cycles.